# trouble installing "gorilla/mux" in golang

Tags: go, gorilla

So I installed gorilla/mux to use it for my API by typing this code on terminal

```
go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
```

And since it didn't return any errors (nor any texts) I thought the install was successful. But When I started to use "mux. "something, vscode showed that the name "mux" is not declared. Does anyone had any similar experience or know how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

(Using go1.18.3)

Comment: Have you configured your GO path?

Comment: Yes, and I just checked that the gorilla/mux file is installed at "go/src/github.com", where the go project I'm currently working on is located at. But it seems like gorilla/mux cannot be imported..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project doesn't have `go.sum` file.

Run `go mod tidy` and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have go installed in your local machine

1. run go mod init githum.com
2. run go get - u github.com/gorilla/mux